# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'int?' C# Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

The Code: It highlights the bottom most part where I can trying to tell Linq to find the shipto column and update the datetimestamp on the other table by a certain amount of minutes and tells me that I cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'int?' and I am unsure of how to continue...

```
  var TestingLinq = (from a in db.shp_master
                     join b in db.shp_status on a.serialnbr equals b.serialnbr into b_join
                     from b in b_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where
                               a.shipto == "1022a" &&
                               a.status == "s" &&
                               b.status == "s" &&
                               a.shpreq == 0
                     group new {a, b} by new {
                               a.serialnbr,
                               a.trailer,
                               a.shipto
                     } into g
                     orderby
                               g.Key.serialnbr
                     select new RecieveTruck {
                               SerialNumber = g.Key.serialnbr,
                               TrailerNumber = (g.Key.trailer ?? "N/A"),
                               Shipped = g.Min(p => p.b.datetimestamp),
                               ETA = 
                               g.Key.shipto == "1026" ? (System.DateTime?)Convert.ToDateTime(g.Min(p => p.b.datetimestamp)).AddMinutes(180) :
                               g.Key.shipto == "2020" ? (System.DateTime?)Convert.ToDateTime(g.Min(p => p.b.datetimestamp)).AddMinutes(195) :
                               g.Key.shipto == "2017" ? (System.DateTime?)Convert.ToDateTime(g.Min(p => p.b.datetimestamp)).AddMinutes(180) : 
                               g.Key.shipto == "nor" ? (System.DateTime?)Convert.ToDateTime(g.Min(p => p.b.datetimestamp)).AddMinutes(180) : null
                     });
  return View(TestingLinq);
```

Gives me the error in the title....
I was trying to convert this SQL Query to Linq:

```
SELECT a.serialnbr, ISNULL(a.trailer, 'N/A') AS 'trailer', MIN(b.datetimestamp) AS 'datetimestamp', 
             CASE WHEN a.shipto = '1026' THEN DATEADD(mi, 180, MIN(b.datetimestamp)) 
                  WHEN a.shipto = '2020' THEN DATEADD(mi, 195, MIN(b.datetimestamp)) 
                  WHEN a.shipto = '2017' THEN DATEADD(mi, 180, MIN(b.datetimestamp)) 
                  WHEN a.shipto = 'nor' THEN DATEADD(mi, 180, MIN(b.datetimestamp)) 
                  ELSE NULL END AS 'eta' 
             FROM shp_master AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN shp_status AS b ON a.serialnbr = b.serialnbr 
             WHERE a.shipto = '1022a' AND a.status = 's' AND b.status = 's' AND a.shpreq = 0 
             GROUP BY a.serialnbr, a.trailer, shipto 
             ORDER BY a.serialnbr
```

Comment: Thank you for the editing help Selman22

Comment: This is a compiler error, not a runtime one, right? It sounds like one, I just want to make sure.

Comment: The problem is that you have a property of type `int?` and you're attempting to assign a `datetime?` into it. It seems that `RecieveTruck.Shipped` and `RecieveTruck.ETA` fit this description. How are they declared?

Comment: public class RecieveTruck
    {
        public int SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public string? TrailerNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime Shipped { get; set; }
        public int? ETA { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Perhaps you could explain to us *what the meaning is* of your ETA variable.  Is it the relative time (in minutes) of arrival compared to some other time (which I don't see in your code), or is it the absolute time (i.e. calendar date & time) of arrival?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment, you specified that `RecieveTruck.ETA` is an `int?`, but you're assigning it by doing

```
 ETA = g.Key.shipto == "1026" ? (System.DateTime?)Convert.ToDateTime(g.Min(p => p.b.datetimestamp)).AddMinutes(180) :
       g.Key.shipto == "2020" ? (System.DateTime?)Convert.ToDateTime(g.Min(p => p.b.datetimestamp)).AddMinutes(195) :
       g.Key.shipto == "2017" ? (System.DateTime?)Convert.ToDateTime(g.Min(p => p.b.datetimestamp)).AddMinutes(180) : 
       g.Key.shipto == "nor" ? (System.DateTime?)Convert.ToDateTime(g.Min(p => p.b.datetimestamp)).AddMinutes(180) : null
```

And that will resolve to a `DateTime?`. You'll need to choose one or the other. It looks like you're looking for `ETA` to be a `DateTime?`, though, so I'd just change that property type and you should be good to go.

Comment: I dont want to assigned ETA to that... I should have put ETA = null, and then specificed another variable for the datetime to be stored into?

Comment: If that's what you choose. I don't know nearly enough about your project to be able to tell you how to design the code for it. But yeah, if you need `ETA` to be of type `int?`, and you need the information you're getting from that immediate-if set, then you should pull it out into two separate properties.

Comment: Yes, worked fine... I just set ETA = null ... then created a new var in my class and added that to = the cases like you suggested with ETA and it worked! Thanks